# Query to find all people who have had a child with more than one person

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I need to find the list of all people who have had a child with more than one person.  I am using one table that has the person name, person ID.  The person's ID also serves as their mother_ID and father_ID.

---

```
ID  NAME    Father ID   Mother ID
1   Paul        
2   Debbie      
3   Jessie      
4   Pam         1          3
5   Sue         1          3
6   Trish       1          3 
7   Sarah       1          2
9   John        
10  johnny      9          4
11  Ben         9          4
```

In the example above, I want to find Paul who has four children with two different people, Debbie and Jessie.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select * from 
your_table a where
(select count(distinct father_id, mother_id)
from your_table b where b.father_id=a.id or b.mother_id=a.id)>1;
```

See [it run on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/978890).

Comment: Nice usage of `COUNT(DISTINCT col1, col2)` :) I would exchange or with in. [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/978890/9/0)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `COUNT(DISTINCT col) > 1`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE Id IN (
    SELECT Father_Id
    FROM table
    GROUP BY Father_Id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Mother_id) > 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Mother_Id
    FROM table
    GROUP BY Mother_Id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Father_Id) > 1
    );
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6cc54fb530812e8e94958e4a188c22eb)**